# jquery - prevent click and touchstart actions on any child elements of e.target

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code setup:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function (e) {
    if ( (!$(e.target).hasClass('sb')) ) {
     $('#features .sb .screen').animate({ top: '6.438em' }, 150);
    }
}
```

to modify the following code:

```
<div class="item">

<div class="sb">
<p>
<a class="title" href="#">my title</a>
<a href="#">some other link</a>
</p>
</div>

</div>
```

How do I tell the target to not only ignore any actions if the element hasClass of sb, but to also not take action on any child elements like the nested p, .title, or  link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if it is a child by using [**closest()**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and `length`

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function (e) {
    if ( !$(e.target).closest('.sb').length ) {
     $('#features .sb .screen').animate({ top: '6.438em' }, 150);
    }
}
```

You will not need to check with `hasClass()` since `closest()` will begin with the element itself

Comment: I dont think you even need `.hasClass` if `.closest()` is used. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla, actually you do because if the `.sb` itself is clicked, `closest` will not detect it

Comment: wow this is the first time in 3 years I can see the true power of closest().  Thank you!

Comment: `.closest()` begins with the current element itself. http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @blackhawk, `closest` really is one of my favorite methods :)

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla, WOOOOW!! You just taught me something new that Ive overlooked for years!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: You guys rock.  thanks again.  This helped to ehance my code.